# Why is this VB code failing on me?

Tags: vb.net

Hers the form code:

```
Imports TechSupportData

Public Class frmOpenIncidents

Private Sub frmOpenIncidents_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim incidentList As List(Of Incident)
    Try
        incidentList = IncidentDB.GetIncidents
        If incidentList.Count > 0 Then
            Dim incident As Incident
            For i As Integer = 0 To incidentList.Count - 1
                incident = incidentList(i)
                lvIncidents.Items.Add(incident.ProductCode)
                lvIncidents.Items(i).SubItems.Add(incident.DateOpened)
                lvIncidents.Items(i).SubItems.Add(incident.CustomerID)
                lvIncidents.Items(i).SubItems.Add(incident.TechID)
                lvIncidents.Items(i).SubItems.Add(incident.Title)
            Next
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("All Incidents are taken care of")
            Me.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.GetType.ToString)
        Me.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

And heres the class its working with:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class IncidentDB
    Public Shared Function GetIncidents() As List(Of IncidentDB)
        Dim incidentList As New List(Of IncidentDB)
        Dim connection As SqlConnection = TechSupportDB.GetConnection
        Dim selectStatement As String _
            = "SELECT CustomerID, ProductCode, TechID, DateOpened, Title" _
            & "FROM(Incidents)" _
            & "WHERE DateClosed IS NULL"
        Dim selectCommand As New SqlCommand(selectStatement, connection)
        Try
            connection.Open()
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader()
            Dim incident As Incident
            Do While reader.Read
                incident = New Incident
                incident.IncidentID = reader("IncidentID").ToString
                incident.CustomerID = reader("CustomerID").ToString
                incident.ProductCode = reader("ProductCode").ToString
                incident.DateOpened = reader("DateOpened").ToString
            Loop
            reader.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            connection.Close()
        End Try
        Return incidentList
    End Function
End Class
```

Heres the error I'm getting from Visual Studio:

Error   1   Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TechSupportData.IncidentDB)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of TechSupportData.Incident)'.   C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\School\Current\ITECH4269 Visual Basic\Assignment2CodyStewart\Assignment2CodySteawrt\Assignment2CodySteawrt\frmOpenIncidents.vb    8   28  Assignment2CodySteawrt

Any guidance or suggestions would be much appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class frmOpenIncidents you've defined `incidentList` as a list of Incidents:

```
Dim incidentList As List(Of Incident)
```

then set it:

```
incidentList = IncidentDB.GetIncidents
```

But that IncidentDB method is defined as returning a list of Incident*DB*:

```
Public Shared Function GetIncidents() As List(Of IncidentDB)
```

Solution might be to change the first definition to this?

```
Dim incidentList As List(Of IncidentDB)
```

You need to choose a name for the class - Incident or IncidentDB - and use it consistently to get rid of all similar errors.

Comment: That solved that error, thanks man! Now im stuck with this one:


Error 1 Value of type 'TechSupportData.IncidentDB' cannot be converted to 'TechSupportData.Incident'. C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\School\Current\ITECH4269 Visual Basic\Assignment2CodyStewart\Assignment2CodySteawrt\Assignment2CodySteawrt\frmOpenIncidents.vb 12 32 Assignment2CodySteawrt

Comment: Looks like its the other way round: Should be `Public Shared Function GetIncidents() As List(Of Incident)` I suspect.

Comment: @Filburt - sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: @Cody - I added an extra note.  You seem to have a mixture of references to classes IncidentDB and Incident.  You probably want to just use one, or have a clearly defined way to transform between the two if you need both for some reason that is not apparent in the code posted.

Comment: ... and of course `Dim incidentList As List(Of Incident)` to be complete.

Comment: Might also consider different namespaces, so you can use a prefix to keep the data class distinct.

Comment: I've decided to go with IncidentDB and that solved the majority of the problems but I'm not faced with something else. I'll update my original post above.